# Why is the static storage behaving differently in the two examples?

Tags: c, static

So here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    static int i=0;
    printf("%d",i);
    static int i=0;
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me an error:
`error: redefinition of 'i'`

Now here is another Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void increment(void) {
    static unsigned int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    printf("%d ", counter);
}

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        increment();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the output :
`1 2 3 4 5`

***Why does this happen ?***
In the second example by calling the function aren't we redeclaring it? And shouldn't the output be `1 1 1 1 1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the second example by calling the function aren't we redeclaring it?

No, we aren't: We are declaring `i` in a **different scope**; specifically, in the body of a different function. You can only define a variable once within a given scope (ignoring sub-scopes); but you can define a variable of the same name in different scopes:

```
int i; // global scope

void foo()
{
    int i; // scope - body of foo
    {
        int i; // a sub-scope of the body of foo
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i; // a different scope - body of main, not body of foo
}
```

and the "closest" definition to a command is the one which will be relevant; it will ["shadow"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the other variables of the same name which might otherwise be usable in that scope.

Of course, it's not a good idea to define many variables with the same name which may shadow each other - it's confusing and their names will likely not be meaningful. People often use a one-letter variable for a loop counter: `i`, `j`, `k` etc. - but then you would tend avoid using `i` for something more long-lasting.

> `1 2 3 4 5`...
> Why does this happen ?

Because within the `increment()` function, the `counter` is a `static unsigned int`, meaning it has [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/static_storage_duration) - it is only initialized once, and maintains its value between invocations of the function.